# How to calculate the total energy from a given wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

For a given wavefunction, $\Psi(x,t)$ of a system, how one can calculate the total energy?

For example, the wavefunction for a particle of mass $m$ moving in a certain potential $U(x)$ is given by: (where $A$, $L$, $E$ are real constants.)

$$\Psi(x,t)=\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        (Ax)e^{-\frac{x}{L}}\;e^{-i\frac{Et}{\hbar}}\;&,&x>0 \\
        0\;&,&x\leq0
    \end{matrix}
\right.$$

How one can express the potential energy $U(x)$ and total energy $E$ in terms of $L$, $m$, $\hbar$?

Comment: Unless this is an energy eigenfunction, it does not have a well defined energy. If you want to calculate the expectation value of the energy, just apply the Hamiltonian operator (which requires knowing $U(x)$), multiply by the complex conjugate $\Psi^*$, and integrate.

Comment: You cannot express the potential in terms of the energy levels of the great multiplicity of wavefunctions. There is one potential function introduced in the differential equation and actually an infinity of possible wavefunction solutions of the equation. It is a one to many correlations.

Answer (score 1):

The wave function of the form
$$
\Psi(x,t) = \psi_0(x) e^{-i\frac{Et}{\hbar}}
$$
corresponds to the stationary state of a system with energy $E$. This fact implies that $\psi_0(x)$ is an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian operator:
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi_0''(x) + U(x)\psi_0(x) = E\psi_0(x).
$$
Knowlege of $\psi_0(x)$ and $E$ allows finding the potential $U(x)$ from last equation:
$$
U(x) = E + \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\psi_0''(x)}{\psi_0(x)}.
$$
For the $\psi_0(x)$ from the example, it is easy to calculete $U(x)$ for $x>0$. $\psi_0(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$ implies that $U(x) = +\infty$ in this area.